# Read data into Matlab using URL

Tags: url, matlab

I want to read weather data from Weather Unground into Matlab directly. For a given site you can select to output the data in comma delimited format. How can I write a Matlab function that will read in the information into Matlab? I don't want to download the file but rather read it in from the URL.

For example, here is a [URL](http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=MC9780&format=1) of some data. Is there some Matlab function that has a URL as an input and saves data from whatever it finds there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [URLREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/urlread.html) is what you're looking for. For example, using your URL above gives the following output:

```
>> str = urlread('http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=MC9780&format=1');

str =


Time,TemperatureF,DewpointF,PressureIn,WindDirection,WindDirectionDegrees,WindSpeedMPH,WindSpeedGustMPH,Humidity,HourlyPrecipIn,Conditions,Clouds,dailyrainin,SoftwareType<br>
2010-09-27 00:09:00,56.0,52.0,30.05,NNE,25,0.0,3.0,86,0.00,,,0.00,,
<br>
2010-09-27 00:17:00,56.0,52.0,30.05,NNE,25,0.0,3.0,86,0.00,,,0.00,,
<br>
2010-09-27 00:28:00,56.0,52.0,30.04,NNE,30,2.0,5.0,85,0.00,,,0.00,,
<br>
...
```

Now you just have to parse the string output to get the information you want.

If you would rather read from the URL and save it to a file instead of loading it as a string variable, you can use the function [URLWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/urlwrite.html).

Comment: CDF parsing can be handled by Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/netcdf.html

Comment: @rwong, care to elaborate please? I never heard of netcdf before

Comment: +1: Answer is correct.  But what a terrible choice of function names on Mathworks' part!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I assume you're referring to URLWRITE, and I would have to agree. Usually functions that have "read" and "write" in their names would be expected to perform complementary actions, like reading *from* a file and writing *to* a file. Since URLWRITE actually reads *then* writes, I think they should rename it to something like URLSAVE. In fact, I think I'll go to the documentation page and suggest it right now! ;)

Comment: @gnoivce, I agree URLSAVE is much better

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Sorry, NetCDF and CDF are totally different formats. My apologies. The MATLAB documentation for CDF is http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cdflib.html

Comment: I used `urlwrite(url,tmpfile);S=load(tmpfile);` to make a local copy and load a remote .mat data file.